# RecyclerView in viewPager above EditText

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm building a messaging app with a viewPager to tab between multiple conversations. I have a RecyclerView in the layout inflated in the viewPager that contains my chat messages. I also have an EditText at the bottom of the layout to add a message to the RecyclerView. However when I add a new message to the adapter it is covered up by the editText. I would like the messages to remain over the input EditText like in other common messaging apps.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/conversation_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    />



<include layout="@layout/input_bar"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and the EditText Layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:background="@color/input_background"
    android:id="@+id/inputLL"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/input_editText_margin"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:hint="Type your message..."
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        >
    </EditText>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/send_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/input_button_selector"
        android:clickable="true"
        >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/send"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_send_black_24dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/input_send_margin"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[before adding message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAqw1.png)

[after adding message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItITG.png)

Comment: Please post your xml code with the EditText.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> CoordinatorLayout is a super-powered FrameLayout.

So the `TextView` will overlap the `ViewPager`. I recommend you use a `RelativeLayout` to contain your `ViewPager` and `TextView`. Place `TextView` at the bottom of parent, then put `ViewPager` above it.